# indentation level error to build database

Tags: python, syntax-error

i get this code from a sentiment analysis tutorial...but what is wrong in this code...here error produced

```
def huffingtonRSSvisit():
    try:
        page = 'http://feeds.huffingtonpost.com/huffingtonpost/raw_feed'
        sourceCode = opener.open(page) .read()
        try:
            links = re.findall(r'<link.*href=\"(.*?)\"', sourceCode)
            for link in links:
                if '.rdf' in link:
                    pass
                else:
                    print 'visiting the link'
                    print '########################'
                    linkSource = opener.open(link) .read()
                    linesOfInterest = re.findall(r'<p>(.*?)</p>',str(linkSource))
                    print 'Content:'
                    for eachLine in linesOfInterest:
                        if '<img width' in eachLine:
                            pass
                        elif '<a href=' in eachLine:
                            pass
                        else:
                            print eachLine



                        time.sleep(5)

         except Exception, e:
         print 'failed main loop of huffingtonRSS'
         print str(e)
```

> File "", line 28
>       except Exception, e:                    ^
>   IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: It would be better to add the tag of the language ur using to ur question (PLUS: u'll get the [editor](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3/editor) badge).

Comment: What language is this? Python, I assume.

Answer (score 0):

Every try: block needs to be matched with an exception clause.  Since your code has two `try:` lines, you need two exception blocks:

```
def huffingtonRSSvisit():
    try:
        page = 'http://feeds.huffingtonpost.com/huffingtonpost/raw_feed'
        sourceCode = opener.open(page) .read()
        try:
            links = re.findall(r'<link.*href=\"(.*?)\"', sourceCode)
            for link in links:
                if '.rdf' in link:
                    pass
                else:
                    print 'visiting the link'
                    print '########################'
                    linkSource = opener.open(link) .read()
                    linesOfInterest = re.findall(r'<p>(.*?)</p>',str(linkSource))
                    print 'Content:'
                    for eachLine in linesOfInterest:
                        if '<img width' in eachLine:
                            pass
                        elif '<a href=' in eachLine:
                            pass
                        else:
                            print eachLine    
                        time.sleep(5)
         except Exception, e:
             print 'failed inner try block of huffingtonRSS'
             print str(e)
     except Exception, e:
         print 'failed outer try block of huffingtonRSS'
         print str(e)
```